# mvvm binding is updating intermittently

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have a counter on a a page just below a datagrid and I am trying to use it to notify the user of how many rows are in the datagrid and how many rows are expected ("1 of 900"). The textbox that is in question is being updated but on when the count is being changed for each row. It is updating after 400+ rows have been inserted into the datagrid.

The model property:

```
    public string CountText
    {
        get
        {
            return countText;
        }
        set
        {
            countText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CountText");
        }
    }
```

The wpf textbox:

```
    // wpf textbox
    <TextBox
         Margin="10,0,0,0" 
         x:Name="CountText" 
         Style="{StaticResource EtchedTextBoxWhiteOnBlack}" 
         Background="Transparent" 
         Height="50" Width="200" 
         FontSize="22" FontWeight="ExtraBold"
         Text="{Binding EventLogModel.CountText}" 
         TextAlignment="Center"
         HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
         HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" />
```

The code updating the CountText property in the model:

```
    // model property to which the textbox is bound
    public string CountText
    {
        get
        {
            return countText;
        }
        set
        {
            countText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CountText");
        }
    }

    // code snippet that is updating the datagrid and the string property to which the textbox is bound
    bool bContinue = true;
    int startIndex = 0;
    int chunkSize = 50;
    bool breset = EventLogSignalingEvent.Reset();
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(GetNumberOfLogEntries, lp);
    bool bwait = EventLogSignalingEvent.WaitOne();

    count = 0;

    if (maxItems > 0)
                {
                    UpdateStatusDialog("Loading log data", string.Format("{0} items total found", maxItems));
                    CountText = string.Format("{0} of {1}", count.ToString(), maxItems);
                }
                else
                {
                    statusOpen = false;
                    UpdateStatusDialog("No log data found", "");
                    StatusDlgHideEllipse();
                    CountText = string.Format("{0} items found", maxItems);
                }

                while (bContinue && !bStopped)
                {
                    EventLogSignalingEvent.Reset();
                    lp = new LogParams();
                    lp.chunkSize = chunkSize;
                    lp.eDate = eDate;
                    lp.sDate = sDate;
                    lp.startIndex = startIndex;
                    lp.UTCOffset = UTCOffset;
                    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(GetEventLogChunk, lp);
                    EventLogSignalingEvent.WaitOne();

                    if (chunk != null && chunk.Count > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (LogRecordDbMVVM db in chunk)
                        {
                            MainWindow.MainWinDispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Send, new ThreadStart(() =>
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    EventLog.Add(LogRecordGUI.LogRecord_DBtoGUI(db));
                                    Thread.Sleep(10);
                                }
                                catch
                                {
                                }
                            }));

                            if (statusOpen == true)
                            {
                                CloseStatusDialog();
                                statusOpen = false;
                            }

                            if (count < maxItems)
                            {
                                count++;
                                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(UpdateCount, count);
                                //CountText = string.Format("{0} of {1}", count.ToString(), maxItems);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if (chunk == null)
                    {
                        log.Info("############################################### ERROR: chunk == null");
                        log.InfoFormat("Start date = {0} End date = {1} Start index = {2} chunkSize = {3} maxItems = {4}", sDate, eDate, startIndex, chunkSize, maxItems);
                    }

                    startIndex += chunkSize;
                    bContinue = (startIndex >= maxItems) ? false : true;

                }

                EventLogViewCount = (EventLog.Count - NumberOfEventLogItemsInView) >= 0 ? EventLog.Count - NumberOfEventLogItemsInView : 0;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.ErrorFormat("{0} {1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.ErrorFormat("{0} {1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }

    private void UpdateCount(object context)
    {
        int count = (int)context;

        CountText = string.Format("{0} of {1}", count.ToString(), maxItems);
    }

    private void GetNumberOfLogEntries(object context)
    {
        LogParams lp = (LogParams)context;
        maxItems = BT220.ManagementService.GetEventLogCountChunk(lp.sDate, lp.eDate, lp.UTCOffset, lp.startIndex, lp.chunkSize);
        EventLogSignalingEvent.Set();
    }
```

Comment: I don't see a question anywhere in here... what are you asking for help with?

Comment: The underlying value is probably updating so fast the UI thread isn't getting a chance to run.

Comment: My question is why is the count is not getting updated when each record is being added to the datagrid? The count gets updated every  300 entries or so.